# What is causing this recursive function to recur twice the start over again two instances indefinitely?

Tags: javascript, recursion

It logs the string once and the logs 0 and then 1 and the 0 and 1 again indefinitely-why?
The recursion is happening twice and then starting over again, what's causing it to recure twice then resetting n to 0?

```
function recure(str,n=0){
    if(n>10){
        console.log("The End");
        return "";
     }
    console.log(n);
    console.log(str)
    setTimeout(function(){recure(n+1)},1500)
   }
```

Comment: You're not passing a string to the first argument at the recursive call site, so `n` gets the default `0`.

Comment: ...should make a person fall in love with static type systems.

Comment: Your recure function takes two arguments. You are passing only one at the end of the function.

Comment: btw "recure" is spelled "recur"

Comment: If you had done the most basic of debugging, you would not have asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the recursive call `recure(n+1)` makes the value of `n` in every recursive invocation as undefined. As a result `(n>10)` is never true and the function gets called indefinitely with default value of `n=0` and `str=1 (n+1)` from the recursive invocation

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the second argument in your setTimeout function. Try this:

```
function recure(str,n=0){
    if(n>10){
        console.log("The End");
        return "";
     }
    console.log(n);
    console.log(str)
    setTimeout(function(){recure(str, n+1)},1500)
   }
```

Working sample:

https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/2y7q68ny/